# Why isn't the map showing up in my React MapGL component with Mapbox API token?

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, mapbox

I am following the below you tube tutorial and trying to learn mapbox. I imported github project and used the token but still not map showing up. Can you let me know how to fix it . Providing stackblitz below

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JJatzkPcmoI

https://stackblitz.com/edit/github-h2sep1?file=.env.local,src%2FApp.js

```
<ReactMapGL
        {...viewport}
        mapboxApiAccessToken={process.env.REACT_APP_MAPBOX_TOKEN}
        mapStyle="mapbox://styles/leighhalliday/cjufmjn1r2kic1fl9wxg7u1l4"
        onViewportChange={viewport => {
          setViewport(viewport);
        }}
      >
        {parkDate.features.map(park => (
          <Marker
            key={park.properties.PARK_ID}
            latitude={park.geometry.coordinates[1]}
            longitude={park.geometry.coordinates[0]}
          >
            <button
              className="marker-btn"
              onClick={e => {
                e.preventDefault();
                setSelectedPark(park);
              }}
            >
              <img src="/skateboarding.svg" alt="Skate Park Icon" />
            </button>
          </Marker>
        ))}
```

REACT_APP_MAPBOX_TOKEN = "pk.eyJ1IjoicmFqa3VtYXJ0MDgiLCJhIjoiY2xpZmUybjFxMTRkYjNtbzVxYW11azhmbiJ9.u2YJYZcYxi87d0cFw0KD5Q"